# Python: How to print last X character found in a string? What´s wrong with my code that doesn´t always work?

Tags: python, string, indexing

I need to print the position of the last time I encounter a specific character, in a given string. How may I do that?
ie. For this string "alahambra", I need to find the last time the letter "a" appears, so the result should be: 8.

I´ve tried this code, but it doesn´t always work:

```
def find_last(search, target):
    first=search.find(search)
    last=len(search)
    result=search.find(target,last-1)
    return result
```

**Examples:**

> print find_last('aaaaa', 'aa')

should print 3, and **it prints -1 instead, that´s wrong!**

> print find_last('aaaa', 'b')

should print -1, and it prints -1, that´s correct.

> print find_last("111111111", "1")

should print 8, and it prints 8, that´s correct.

> print find_last("222222222", "")

should print 9, and **it prints 8 instead, that´s wrong!**

> print find_last("", "3")

should print -1, and it prints -1, that´s correct.

> print find_last("", "")

should print 0, and it prints 0, that´s correct.

What´s wrong in my code and how should I change it? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> "alahambra".rindex('a')
8
>>>
```

This will raise an error if the substring is not found. Use `rfind` will return -1 in this case.

```
>>> "alahambra".rfind('a')
8
>>> 
>>> ''.rfind('b')
-1
>>>
```

Comment: So, use `rfind`, this will return -1 in this case or wrap `rindex` in a `try...except`.

Comment: Sorry, deleted the comment before reading yours :) Yes! It works as expected with rfind!! THANKS!!

Answer (score 1):

you could use `rindex` or `rfind` - http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

```
"alahambra".rfind('a')
```

the difference between them is that `rindex` will raise error when the substring is not found and `rfind` will return -1

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this :

```
>>> def find_last(A,q):
...     k = -1
...     while k < len(A):
...             i = A.find(q,k+1)
...             if i == -1: return k
...             else: k = i
...     return k
...
>>> find_last('aaaaa','aa')
3
>>> find_last("222222222", "")
9
>>> find_last("", "")
0
>>> find_last("", "3")
-1
```